# Why can't player's nudge balls indefinitely in snooker?

Tags: snooker

Below is a position from a match between O'Sullivan and Hendry. Hendry has just nudged the cue ball into the pack of reds.

[image]

Obviously O'Sullivan could just do the same thing, hitting the cue ball into the pack very softly so it just barely touches one of the reds. Then both of them could just do that forever. Is there a rule that prevents this behavior?

Note that in straight pool there are specific rules to prevent this from happening, but in snooker, no such rule seems to exist.

Comment: Could you explain how this is fundamentally different from [your previous question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/what-prevents-players-from-nursing-the-balls-in-snooker)?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Nursing is when you move the balls along the rail, which is different than the situation here in the center of the table.

Comment: But doesn't the same answer you received there apply here as well? That answer even talks about an early frame situation "leaving the racked reds as intact as possible".